# Why and how would you not use a python GUI framework and make one yourself like many applications including Blender do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, blender

I have looked at a few python GUI frameworks like PyQt, wxPython and Kivy, but have noticed there aren’t many popular (used widely) python applications, from what I can find, that use them.

Blender, which is pretty popular, doesn’t seem to use them. How would one go about doing what they did/what did they do and what are the potential benefits over using the previously mentioned frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that python isn't a popular choice when it comes to making a GUI application, which is why you don't find many examples of using the GUI frameworks. tkinter, which is part of the python development is another option for GUI's.

Blender isn't really a good example as it isn't a GUI framework, it is a 3D application that integrates python as a means for users to manipulate it's data. It was started over 25 years ago when the choice of cross platform frameworks was limited, so making their own was an easier choice to make. Python support was added to blender about 13 years ago. One of the factors in blender's choice was to make each platform look identical. That goes against most frameworks that aim to implement a native look and feel for each target platform.

So you make your own framework when the work of starting your own framework seems easier than adjusting an existing framework to your needs, or the existing frameworks all fail to meet your needs, one of those needs may be licensing with Qt and wxWidgets both available under (L)GPL, while Qt also sells non-GPL licensing.

The benefit to using an existing framework is the amount of work that is already done, you will find there is more than you first think in a GUI framework, especially when you start supporting multiple operating systems.